# c# merge list but based on position relative to items in both lists

Tags: c#, list, merge

This is not your typical merge. I basically have 2 or more collections i need to merge and the order of the items is important.  Every instance of the collections will have the items in the same order but an item may or may not be in a collection.  To demonstrate i will use numbers but in real application these are objects.

```
collection_1 = [3,5,7,9]
collection_2 = [2,5,6]
collection_3 = [1,2,3,4,7,8]

After merge of collection 1 and 2 i am looking for
[3,2,5,6,7,9] or [2,3,5,7,9,6] or [3,2,5,7,9,6] are all correct
After merge above with collection 3
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] (other variations possible)
```

The idea is that i will give it a heap of collections to merge one after the other but it needs to not break the order of any of the collections.  Extra items can be added in between but the order must be the same.

i know this is a strange case but it is for code generation where the order of the properties on the class is must be in a particular order so they get serialised out in the same order them came in.  If a property is not populated then it will not be serialised out so that is why i can add items in-between but not change the order. To easily compare input to output in an automated fashion i need them coming out in the same order they went in otherwise it would require manual testing which i don't want to do :)

--- edit ---

Trying to explain it a bit better.

All i can check is if an item in one list equals an item in another list.  These items will be objects not numbers like above and can't be sorted on their contents. The sorting/ordering is based on the order of items relative to items that are in both lists. The only way you can do this is to know that one list is 100% ordered correctly and the second list is a merge so may have things out of order.  My source lists will always been in the same order so can trust them as the point of truth when there is a conflict due to a earlier merge.

I am also working on some possible solutions but no luck yet

Comment: I'm confused how you can have `1` in the collection after merging collections 1 and 2.

Comment: It's difficult to understand your requirements. I see no logic in how you determine that 3 must come before 2 in the first merge, but it's okay for 2 to come before 3 in the second merge. You need to give us a better explanation.

Comment: @paqogomez yea that was a mistake i have removed it

Comment: @JimMischel the 2 and the 3 could be in any order in the first merge. In the first merge i was merging collect 2 into collection 1 so if there is any order part of the order that was unclear it used the collection been merged in.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you should use HashSet to create merged collection, after that use sorting. So you must create custom comparer.
Your requirements difficult to understand, but if order of merged array based on order before merge, you might use wrapper structure to store item location before merge.

Comment: that will not work.  I can only check equality. if you want think of them as strings or words and been ordered in sequence found not alphabetical.  I used numbers as it makes it easier or i thought it would.  It is the order the items are in the lists that is important and their position to items contained in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

After i while i managed to come up with the following method to do this.  It is not perfect but seems to get the order correct 95% of the time. implementation is below for those interested and if anyone has a better implementation i am still interested.

```
public static List<T> OrderdMergeList<T>(this List<T> master, List<T> secondary)
    {
        var output = master.ToList();
        var itemsToInsert = new List<T>();
        int? lastMatchIndex = null;
        foreach (var item in secondary)
        {
            if (output.Contains(item))
            {
                if (!lastMatchIndex.HasValue)
                {
                    //already in the list so insert any items we have before this and not already in the output
                    var index = output.IndexOf(item);
                    output.InsertRange(index, itemsToInsert);
                    itemsToInsert.Clear();
                    lastMatchIndex = output.IndexOf(item);//updates it to new position
                }
                else
                {
                    //already in the list but also already found a match so need to be careful for out of order info
                    var index = output.IndexOf(item);
                    if (index > lastMatchIndex.Value)
                    {
                        output.InsertRange(index, itemsToInsert);
                        itemsToInsert.Clear();
                        lastMatchIndex = output.IndexOf(item); //updates it to new position
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        output.InsertRange(lastMatchIndex.Value+1, itemsToInsert);
                        if (itemsToInsert.Count > 0)
                        {
                            lastMatchIndex = output.IndexOf(itemsToInsert.Last()); //updates it to new position
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            lastMatchIndex += 1;
                        }
                        itemsToInsert.Clear();

                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //not in the output so add it to the list to insert when we find a match
                itemsToInsert.Add(item);        
            }
        }
        //insert any left over items on the end
        output.AddRange(itemsToInsert);
        return output;
        //return master.Union(secondary).ToList();
    }
```